# Number of different arrangements of the letters A,B,C,D,E,F

Tags: combinatorics

How many different arrangements are there of the letters A,B,C,D,E,F in which
(a) A and B are next to each other and C and D are also next to each other?
(b) E is not the last letter?
(c) A is before B?
(d) A is before B and B is before C?
(e) A is before B and C is before D?

I got these answers for (a) and (b) but I'm not sure how to approach (c),(d) and (e).

(a) $4! \times 2! \times 2!$

(b)$6!-5!$

Comment: @Swapnil: C and D are also adjacent; a) and ) and b) are ok.

Comment: @leonbloy Sorry, I took part A as two separate parts. Thanks for pointing that out. Comment deleted.

Comment: @Swapnil Sometimes it's helpful to leave comments like that.. =)

Comment: @Delvacode How, when it was plain wrong?

Comment: @Swapnil Maybe not in this case. Haha.. I felt that one could see other approaches to the problem and see how those approaches could possibly go wrong. Not always of course, sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

c) Take the set of all arrangements. One half has $A$ before $B$, the other half has $B$ before $A$

d) What fraction of all arrangements have $A$, $B$, and $C$ in this order?

e) Same idea as d)

Comment: So the answer for (c) is $6!/2$ right?

Comment: Right. For c)  you will need to divide by something else...

Comment: You mean for part d?

Comment: I'm still not sure for (d). AEFBDC is also a valid combination. So I can't see ABC as single block. Any hints?

Comment: ABCDEF ACBDEF BACDEF BCADEF CABDEF CBADEF

Comment: Still not sure, sorry. Can explain? Thanks!