# Counting arrangements for A, B, C, D, E

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The letters $A, B, C, D , E$ are given. How many possibilities are there that

1. $A$ comes before $B$
2. $A$ comes before $B$ and $B$ comes before $C$
3. $A$ comes before $B$ and $C$ comes before $D$
4. $A$ and $B$ are next to each other
5. $A$ and $B$ are next to each other and $C$ and $D$ are next to each other
6. $E$ is not the last in line.

My solutions:

1. $5!/2$
2. $3!$ because there are $3$ positions in $ABC, D, E$
3. Couldn't solve
4. $4!\times2$ because there are $4$ positions in $AB,C,D,E$ and $4$ positions in $BA, C, D,E$
5. $3!\times4$ because there are  $3$ positions in $AB, CD, E$, $3$ positions in $BA, CD, E$, $3$ positions in $AB, DC, E$, $3$ positions in $BA, DC, E$.
6. $5!-4!$ because if $E$ is at the end, there are $4!$ ways.

Are the solutions correct? How do I solve $3$?

Comment: You should be able to try at least some of these.  For the last one, say...how many permutations are there which do have $E$ as the last entry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of different arrangements of the letters A,B,C,D,E,F](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042503/number-of-different-arrangements-of-the-letters-a-b-c-d-e-f)

Comment: @lonyen11 What I meant was do you know the number of ways n distinct objects can be arranged? If not check out this [website](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/PROOF-of-the-formula-on-the-number-of-permutations.lesson) and go through the proofs. I shall answer your questions assuming you know the formulae in this site.

Comment: yes, i know it. so question 6 must be 5!-4!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please  edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain your reasoning rather than placing that information in the comments, where it might be missed.

Answer (score 2):

We are going ot make use of symmetry to answer $(1),(2),(3)$. Number of ways of arranging $A, B, C, D, E$ without any condition is $5!$.

$(1)$ Notice that since $A$ and $B$ are distinct, in any of these $120$ arrangements we will have either $A$ before $B$ or $B$ before $A$. By symmetry, we get that number of ways of arranging such that $A$ is before $B$ is equal to the number of arrangements with $B$ before $A$. Hence, number of ways of arranging with $A$ before $B$ would be $5!/2$.

> $$5!\cdot\frac{1}{2!}=60$$

$(2)$ $A,B,C$ can be arranged in exactly $3!$ ways. By symmetry, we get that each of these $6$ arrangements will have equal number of ways of arranging $D,E$ anywhere. Hence, we divide the total number of arrangements of $A,B,C,D,E$ by $3!$ to get the possible number of arrangements given that $A,B,C$ are in a fixed order. Number of ways of arranging $A,B,C,D,E$ such that $A,B,C$ are in this very order is $5!/3!$.

> $$5!\cdot\frac{1}{3!}=20$$

Why is your method wrong? It hasn't been given that $A,B,C$ are together, only the order is known. Hence, $E,A,B,D,C$ is also possible. How does the symmetry work? You can swap $A,B,C$ from this permutation in $3!$ ways to get more orders. For instance here, you get $$E,A,C,D,B$$
$$E,B,A,D,C$$
$$E,B,C,D,A$$
$$E,C,A,D,B$$
$$E,C,B,D,A$$
that is, $3!-1$ more orders. For every possible arrangement satisfying the order $A,B,C$, you get $5$ more orders. Suppose there are $x$ possible arrangements with $A$ before $B$ and $B$ before $C$. Then,
$$x+(3!-1)x=5!\Rightarrow x=\frac{5!}{3!}.$$

$(3)$ We follow the previous methods. First consider the number of arrangements such that $A$ occurs before $B$. We do not have conditions on $C,D,E$. Following what we did in $(1)$, we have $60$ permutations. Next we see that in each of these $60$ arrangements, either $C$ will be before $D$ or $D$ comes before $C$. By symmetry, these two cases will have equal arrangements. Therefore, number of ways of arranging with $C$ before $D$ would be $60/2!$ (since, total number of arrangements after fixing the order of $A,B$ is $60$ and not $5!$).

> $$5!\cdot\frac{1}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}=30$$

$(4),(5),(6)$ have correct arguments and answers.

Comment: thank you. could you add it though? perhaps, it it would help me to understand.

Comment: @lonyen11 First go through these easy to understand sites [Introduction to Combinations](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/Introduction-to-Combinations-.lesson) and [Proof for the Combination formula](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/PROOF-of-the-formula-on-the-number-of-combinations.lesson).